# Can I lose spells by breaking Dark Souls's covenants?

Tags: dark-souls

**Can I lose spells by breaking Dark Souls's covenants?**

To be more specific, I'm interested whether I can join [Chaos Servant Covenant](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/chaos-servant), offer 30 humanities, get Great Chaos Fireball & Chaos Storm by doing so, and then join another covenant and still have these two spells available for me afterwards?

Comment: I don't think so... but I don't have the game anymore so I can't test it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but not for Chaos Servant.

The following are the covenants which will remove your access to spells upon betrayal:

- [Warrior of Sunlight](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/warrior-of-sunlight) - Unable to use the miracle [Sunlight Spear](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/sunlight-spear)
- [Princess's Guard](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/princess-s-guard) - Unable to use the miracles [Soothing Sunlight](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/soothing-sunlight) or [Bountiful Sunlight](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/bountiful-sunlight)
- [Blade of the Darkmoon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/blade-of-the-darkmoon) - Unable to use the miracle [Darkmoon Blade](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/darkmoon-blade)

It's also worth noting that betraying the [Gravelord Servant](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/gravelord-servant) covenant will cause the miracles [Gravelord Sword Dance](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/gravelord-sword-dance) and [Gravelord Greatsword Dance](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/gravelord-greatsword-dance) to deal reduced damage.

Comment: Thanks. Is this correct that spells doesn't not removed, but you simple can not cast them, like it is said in Soothing Sunlight and Bountiful Sunlight wiki? (And if yes, then are you sure about Sunlight Spear, wiki says nothing about it).

Comment: @klm123 re-read the wiki about sunlight spear, it says on the spell page under 'general information'. You can equip it but not cast it.